# SSRS Report Builder 3: can't move or add some items

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have existing reports that were fine in Report Builder 3, but now when I go into design mode and click on an item, the 4 arrow movement icon shows, but I cannot move any item with the mouse. I can move them with the keyboard though.

Also, I cannot insert charts, tables, matrix, or list items. When I click on those on the ribbon, the drop down doesnt even show. The other functions in the report (like making data sources, datasets, etc work, left and right mouse buttons) work fine, except for moving items. I can also right-click somewhere and insert a table or chart, but don't have the wizard option then, and still can't move the items.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Report Builder 3, but no luck. These reports work fine on another computer with Report Builder 3. *New* reports also have the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: ok this is getting stranger -- the same reports, or even BRAND NEW reports opened in BIDS also have the same problem! I cant move items with the mouse! I installed all service packs for sql server 2008R2 and visual studio 2008  - Oh and why would someone give me a down vote? I've been researching this stupid problem ALL DAY

Comment: This is a tough question. At the moment there's not really enough info in the question yet for it to be answered, unless someone coincidentally has had the same problem and recognizes the symptoms. The only thing I can think of is addons/extensions or something else specific to your situation causing this problem. Any additional info may help us help you. Note that you can update (edit) your question at any time to add more info (which also bumps the question, if the edit's significant).

Comment: Okay glad to hear it's solved! You should consider answering your own question so future visitors can see it, or otherwise remove it if you don't think it would help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be my mouse! Never seen a failure like this, where just SOME windows in SOME programs couldn't be moved, but everything else worked. About a week later, it wouldn't move ANY windows, and even unplugging it and plugging in another one didn't fix it, I had to reboot with new mouse attached. Then it was OK. very odd.